# Instant redirect program output to file without buffering from batch file

Tags: c, batch-file, stdout

I have `C` program where the messages are printed with `printf` command. From batch file I call my program with

```
call myProgram.exe parms > myFile.txt
```

I need that `myFile` be updated every time (or almost every time) when `myProgram` print a message. Now, I cannot see anything in file until the program finish its execution, probably because some buffering. Is this buffering problem from my `C` program, from my `batch file` or from operating system, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried to `fflush(stdio)` everytimes you print something ?

Comment: wintail.exe doews that

Comment: @Michael You mean `fflush(stdout)`? I put it after one `printf` the file is still empty.

Comment: @Petar, yes of course, `stdout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdio.h` functions are buffering. See [setvbuf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/setvbuf.html). The buffering may be operating system specific, and may change when redirecting (e.g. because internally [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) could be used inside `printf` etc...).

<sup>Notice that this buffering is actually useful, and generally speeds up output a lot.</sup>

The simplest way is to call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) from time to time. Otherwise call `setvbuf` with `_IOFBF` on `stdout`.

Using `setvbuf` near the start of the program is simpler. However, calling `fflush` at *appropriate places* might be more efficient (because using a larger buffer should be faster).

Comment: I tried `fflush` and `setvbuf` and they are working both. I think `setvbuf` is better solution because it is not need to search for all `printf`s in project and put `fflush(stdout)` after each. Thank you for answer.